# EPSON Printer instantly cancels Job

Tags: printer

I've installed the EPSON driver from their website and can see my EPSON printer connected but when I print to it I almost instantly get a notification that the print job was cancelled. Anyone else have this issue? Any ideas on what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much. Trying to figure out problem for days. This fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with my printer (Epson WF-4740). I removed the printer, downloaded and installed the latest EPSON driver for my model (http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX), and re-added the printer again and I was able to print normally.

Hope this helps.